# How to use gzip and grep with fread from data.table correctly?

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to read data from a gzipped CSV file using `data.table::fread`. Because there are some incomplete rows in the file, I want to use the grep command to extract only well-formatted rows. This part is working fine on command line.
But the following R code is producing an syntax error:

> "{17}')" can not be processed syntactically at this point

(Error message translated from german.)

I am working on a Windows machine using cygwin, if that matters at all.

```
file = "../5601_RawData/test.csv.gz"
test <- fread(paste0("gzip -d -c ",file," | grep -E '(.+;.+){17}'"))
```

Comment: Does your machine have zgrep (able to grep compressed files) and if so, does it work (remove the first half before the pipe, just change the second half to "zgrep -E pattern test.csv.gz")? Alternatively, if you can't get it to work, you could always use a system() command to direct the complete rows into a new file, then read that in.

Comment: thanks a lot! Using system() and creating a temporary file did the trick (well, I had to use shell(), but you pointed me in the right direction).